# add googlemap Fragment in navigationDrawer example

Tags: supportmapfragment

Please every one I try tu use example in url : 
https://github.com/swissonid/android-design-support-lib-sample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ch/swissonid/design_lib_sample/fragments
.
but when i try to add Mapfragment i have error : nullexception in line :
SupportMapFragment frag = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
----->  googleMap = frag.getMap();

i need help 
thank you

Comment: put the code you tried here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all 
if anyone have a problem like me 
I switched to this lib : 
https://github.com/rudsonlive/NavigationDrawer-MaterialDesign
it's very simple to use 
closed

Answer (score 0):

this is my class :
.

```
public class Exp_Main_fragment extends BaseFragment {

@InjectView(R.id.collapsing_toolbar)
CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsingToolbar;

public static Exp_Main_fragment newInstance() {
    return new Exp_Main_fragment();
}
```

private GoogleMap googleMap;
    MarkerOptions marker;

```
public Exp_Main_fragment(){
    setupmap();

}
public void setupmap(){

    if (googleMap == null){

        SupportMapFragment frag = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = frag.getMap();        



        if (googleMap !=null){
            try {
                MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).zoom(7).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }

    }

}
}
```

i follow exemple in this url :
https://github.com/swissonid/android-design-support-lib-sample